# Autosave / autoload content of scratch buffer in Emacs

Tags: emacs, scratch

I would like to assign a file (`~/tmp/scratch`) to the `*scratch*` buffer in Emacs.

When I open Emacs I would like `~/tmp/scratch` to be opened (preferably in the buffer named `*scratch*`) and when Emacs is closed the content should be saved to `~/tmp/scratch`.

Answer (score 9):

See this article : [How to Make Emacs' Scratch Buffer Persistent Across Sessions](http://dorophone.blogspot.fr/2011/11/how-to-make-emacs-scratch-buffer.html).

This article contains the code to put in the .emacs or .emacs.d/init.el file, which will declare the file containing the scratch buffer, load the buffer on startup and save on shutdown.

The code is a bit too voluminous to reproduce here. You should also read the comments to the article.